# HTML Select component and Hibernate with Spring MVC Trouble

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Currently Im working with Spring MVC and Hibernate.

I need some info from a table to a select component in HTML, but it fills with the next info.

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" size="1">
   <option value="{id=1, name=name1}">{id=1, name=name1}</option>
   <option value="{id=2, name=name2}">{id=2, name=name2}</option>
   <option value="{id=3, name=name3}">{id=3, name=name3}</option>
   <option value="{id=4, name=name4}">{id=4, name=name4}</option>
   <option value="{id=5, name=name5}">{id=5, name=name5}</option>
</select><input type="hidden" name="_dept" value="1"/>
```

instead of

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" size="1">
   <option value=1>name1</option>
   <option value=2>name2</option>
   <option value=3>name3</option>
   <option value=4>name4</option>
   <option value=5>name5</option>
</select><input type="hidden" name="_dept" value="1"/>
```

But I want the object filled just with the name and the id as the value.

My JSP code for the html component

```
<form:select path="dept" size="1">
    <form:options items="${departments}"/>
</form:select>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/dept")
public ModelAndView dept(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam int idKey) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();


    mav.addObject("departments", DAO.ListCombo(-1, -1));
    mav.setViewName("User.jsp");

    return mav;
}
```

My DAO

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public Map<String, String> ListComboDepts(int startResult, int maxRows) throws DataAccessException {
    Query query = createNamedQuery("ComboDepts", startResult, maxRows);

    Map Data = new HashMap();
    Map<String,String> deptos = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    deptos = (Map<String, String>) query.getResultList();

    return deptos;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is looking good just need to iterate your records on JSP, PFB code snippet

```
<select id="dept" name="dept">
<c:forEach var="department" items="${departments}">
    <option value="${department.id}">${department.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot about jstl lib.